# How to migrate data from flashback data archive to new database?

Tags: database, oracle11g

We are in the process of migrating 11.2.0.3.0 database from AIX-64 bit to Linux 64 bit. On AIX, we configured flashback data archive for around 30 tables with retention period of 1 year. Question is, if in future if we had to restore data for a table from flashback data archive which was configured on AIX system to the migrated database in Linux, How do I achieve this?

Please advise.

Thank you,
SA